# How do I send a query parameter which have '+' in the string in the value

Tags: python, django, urlencode

I have a webapp on django. My url is http://localhost?state=mCLap0iv7XYFOZBG/WKv/EZBAC6butVk2tuJC44o8q/6U6PdDbPhxPQl4cTxAmvU06/s1HpkpJWqwqK8fbWECoydMYQjOBqyOzhStK24pVhM3OUejfPLR4JVIwVO9VEAtL0DjToYArBcC8mG/3bm0LYmLUbwcrulTBsLtd+eSkY=&code=aa28b2256deeaf311fa4b4311807f4a

I am getting this string by doing

```
bin_data = RSAKey.encrypt(string) 
encoded_data = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bin_data)
```

On backend when I check the get parameter I get mCLap0iv7XYFOZBG/WKv/EZBAC6butVk2tuJC44o8q/6U6PdDbPhxPQl4cTxAmvU06/s1HpkpJWqwqK8fbWECoydMYQjOBqyOzhStK24pVhM3OUejfPLR4JVIwVO9VEAtL0DjToYArBcC8mG/3bm0LYmLUbwcrulTBsLtd eSkY=  .

Here"+" is getting replaced by " ". The string is encrypted by RSA in python.

Basically I want to do a base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded_string) on the string.

Screenshot from chrome inspector networks tab :
[image]

Comment: You need to urlencode() values to pass them through query strings safely

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The whole point of `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()` is that it doesn't use `+` and `/`, which are *not* safe to use in URLs. Can you show the part where you actually building this URL?

Comment: Added a screenshot. Chrome too is doing it. I tried it on postman, requests library. Same issue everywhere.